# Is there any way to calculate sum of node attributes in NetworkX

Tags: python, networkx

I have the following network:

```
df = pd.DataFrame([
    {'Material': 'FG', 'Component': 'COMP1'},
    {'Material': 'FG', 'Component': 'COMP2'},
    {'Material': 'COMP1', 'Component': 'RAW1'},
    {'Material': 'COMP1', 'Component': 'RAW2'},
    {'Material': 'COMP2', 'Component': 'RAW3'},
    {'Material': 'COMP3', 'Component': 'RAW4'}
])
G = nx.from_pandas_edgelist(df, source='Material', target='Component', create_using=nx.DiGraph)
```

[image]

After assigning an attribute to each node

```
G.nodes['FG']['t'] = 2
G.nodes['COMP1']['t'] = 3
G.nodes['COMP2']['t'] = 5
G.nodes['COMP3']['t'] = 1
G.nodes['RAW1']['t'] = 6
G.nodes['RAW2']['t'] = 4
G.nodes['RAW3']['t'] = 1
G.nodes['RAW4']['t'] = 8
```

I would like to calculate the maximum sum of attribute 't' from selected node's descendants. In other words, to write a function:

```
max_att_sum(G, node, att)
```

whitch for example above returns, i.e.:

```
[in]  max_att_sum(G, 'COMP1', 't)
[out] 9
```

9, because 'RAW1' (6) + 'COMP1' (3) > 'RAW2' (4) + 'COMP1' (3)

Does someone have any idea how to approach this problem?

Comment: The maximum sum among all descendants? As in the descending path with the maximum sum?

Comment: I need only the sum from the path with the maximum sum.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've already found a solution. However, if you know a more effective solution, I will be grateful to learn it.

Step 1. Add weight to each edge:

```
for e in nx.edges(G):
    if nx.descendants(G, e[1]):
        G[e[0]][e[1]]['weight'] = G.nodes[e[0]]['t']
    else:
        G[e[0]][e[1]]['weight'] = G.nodes[e[0]]['t'] + G.nodes[e[1]]['t']
```

Step 2. Function to calculate longest path:

```
def max_att_sum(G, node, attr):
    if nx.descendants(G, node):
        return nx.dag_longest_path_length(G.subgraph(nx.descendants(G, node) | set([node])))
    else:
        return G.nodes[node][attr]
```